# Checking whether a scoped enum contains a value

Tags: c++, enums

I haven't seen a clear answer to this question about enums. Lets say I have an enum:

```
enum class TileType
{
    WALL= 'W',
    PASSAGE= 'P',
    MONSTER = 'M',
    CRYSTAL= 'C',
};
```

and I want to typecast and make a new enum with a char
Lets say the input char is undefined it the enum:

```
char id = 'A';
```

Now when I typecast it there is an undefined behaviour:

```
TileType type = static_cast<TileType>(id);
```

Thats why I want to check if the id is a valid value for an enum

```
//check if enum contains id
bool checkID(char id){...}
```

Now I have a couple ideas to do it but they seem like over kill to me. I also couldn't find a way to iterate over the enum class to make the check easy but I don't think that's possible.

Is there a way to easily check if the enum contains the id so that I can decide if I can typecast or not? Or am I supposed to do like a switch statement and check for every single case?

Comment: the range of the enum depends on the underlying type not on its enumerators. Its more like you have some `int` with named constants `WALL = 1` etc.

Comment: I don't really understand what this means and how this helps with the problem at hand? So are the enum types all have a corresponding int value automatically assigned to them, if thats the case how would I use that to my advantage anyways?

Comment: *there is an undefined behaviour* - That cast is not undefined behaviour.

Comment: Oh ok so what happens when I typecast A in this case? Would it be better if I said "unwanted" behaviour?

Comment: I see, I assume it would be bad practice to get this unspecified value and than check if its correct or not is that correct?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do what you want to do without putting all your enumerated values into a container and searching that container for the proposed value.

Comment: In that respect enums are not very much different from plain integers. There is no simple way to verify that `enum` object holds a value equal to some enumerator. Enums can legally hold any value of an underlying type. For example, take a look at [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) - it's defined as `enum class` with an empty enumerator list.

Comment: Thats a shame, I wish the enums were a bit more flexible in cpp. Would it make any difference if the values were ints instead of chars or is it just not possible for any scoped enum to check by value?

Comment: what i meant is that your enum `TileType` does have values `'A'`, `'B'` ,`'D'`, etc. they just dont have names

Comment: *I wish the enums were a bit more flexible in cpp.*  Aye, agreed.  Alas.  To paraphrase Rumsfeld, "You don't go programming with the `enum` semantics you want, you go programming with the `enum` semantics you have."

Answer (score 2):

> Or am I supposed to do like a switch statement and check for every single case?

This is probably a decent solution. Like this:

```
switch(id) {
    case char(TileType::WALL):
    case char(TileType::PASSAGE):
    case char(TileType::MONSTER):
    case char(TileType::CRYSTAL):
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
}
```

Another alternative is to store all valid values in a data structure such as an array:

```
constexpr std::array valid {
    char(TileType::WALL),
    char(TileType::PASSAGE),
    char(TileType::MONSTER),
    char(TileType::CRYSTAL),
};
```

With such data structure, you can check validity like this:

```
return std::ranges::find(valid, id) != valid.end();
```

Compilers tend to be better at optimising the switch.

---

In either case, it may be useful to use meta-programming to generate the switch / the array.

Comment: Yeah I feel like this is the most logical way to do it. However if I do it like this if I add a new enum variable I would need to add a switch case too which I wanted to avoid cause im trying to do stuff the most oop way as possible rn.

Comment: @ChrisCross That's why I'm suggesting meta programming.

Comment: What do you mean by that im not really familiar with the term meta programming?

Comment: @ChrisCross Write a program that writes the program for you. In this case, write a meta program that reads the enum from the code and generates the code for the switch or the array. Run that meta program before compiling the actual program. The meta program that writes the C++ program doesn't have to be written in C++ itself.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to do this. One way is to use a third-party library like [magic_enum](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum), which may still have limitations on the enum's range.

```
enum class TileType
{
    WALL= 'W',
    PASSAGE= 'P',
    MONSTER = 'M',
    CRYSTAL= 'C',
};

bool contains = magic_enum::enum_contains<TileType>('A');
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xqaceGrEP)

Comment: My libraries are sadly limited to standard libraries only.

Comment: `magic_num` is a *header-only* library, just copy and paste it.

Comment: That would be plagiarism since this is for a homework.

Comment: @ChrisCross Using a fit-for-purpose third party lib (not copy-pasting it but using it) is a good software development way of thinking. You could always _also_ provide the home-written exhaustive switch statement approach, but it is a sub-part approach for a project which would allow using `magic_enum`, particularly as you need to manually remember to expand the switch case whenever you update the associated enum.